# Access web service with basic authentication

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I need to access a Web Service with authentication. They give me SOAP and WSDL. I can input username/password in SoapUI and get response. They told me they use Basic Authentication in Web Service. But how are username and password transferred? LIke htp://xxx/xxxService?userId=&password=? Or are username/password saved in Soap message?

And how can I deal with username/password in the client code generated by wsimport? Where can I input them?

I am using jax-ws, wsgen and wsimport to access the service.

Comment: Did you google? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: no offense but this question is too wide... 
basic name auth.. sure... what ws framework are you using? based on that only, the solution is different... say you're using axis.. then it's rampart.. if you're using spring-ws... then you use spring stack.. please, when you make question, add some context....

Comment: I user Jax-WS, wsgen and wsimport.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert myself but if you're using basic auth with JAX-WS you can use

```
   Authenticator myAuth = new Authenticator(){
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            String user="user",pass="pass";
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass.toCharArray());
        }
    };

    Authenticator.setDefault(myAuth);
```

I call this inside method actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae), when I call the action of a button, and it works perfectly fine. I've read that this is a security risk, but for basic test it works really fine.